# 400/500 error handler in Express - sending JSON vs HTML

Tags: html, json, express

We have this error handler in Express:

```
app.use(function (err, req, res, next) {

  res.status(err.status || 500);

  const stck = String(err.stack || err).split('\n').filter(function (s) {
    return !String(s).match(/\/node_modules\// && String(s).match(/\//));
  });

  const joined = stck.join('\n');
  console.error(joined);

  const isProd = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production';

  const message = res.locals.message = (err.message || err);
  const shortStackTrace = res.locals.shortStackTrace = isProd ? '' : joined;
  const fullStackTrace = res.locals.fullStackTrace = isProd ? '': (err.stack || err);


  if (req.headers['Content-Type'] === 'application/json') {
    res.json({
      message: message,
      shortStackTrace: shortStackTrace,
      fullStackTrace: fullStackTrace
    });
  }
  else {
    //locals for template have already been set
    res.render('error');
  }

});
```

My question is - we want to send back either JSON or HTML depending on the type of request. I assume looking at Content-Type header is the best way to do this. Is there any other way I should be checking?

Isn't the Content-Type header sometimes called 'content-type' (lowercase)?

Answer (score 2):

I prefer using the following (this is for a 404 error but that's not important):

```
if (req.accepts('html')) {
  // Respond with html page.
  fs.readFile('404.html', 'utf-8', function(err, page) {
    res.writeHead(404, { 'Content-Type': 'text/html' });
    res.write(page);
    res.end();
  });
} else {
  if (req.accepts('json')) {
    // Respond with json.
    res.status(404).send({ error: 'Not found' });
  } else {
    // Default to plain-text. send()
    res.status(404).type('txt').send('Not found');
  }
}
```

Basically you can use the `req` object's `accepts` method to find out what you should send as a response.

Comment: thanks, I will look into how the req.accepts method works